# Flask SQLAlchemy - ondelete='CASCADE' not deleting "POSTS" of a "USER". (Using SQLite database)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my tables. I am using SQLite Database.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                            default=datetime.utcnow)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author',
                            lazy=True, passive_deletes=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.email}', '{self.username}', '{self.date_joined}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    link = db.Column(db.String(300))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                            default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.body}', '{self.link}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

This is the deletion of the "USER" route, it deletes the user but doesn't remove the posts created by the user.

```
@login_required
@app.route('/delete/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_account():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        db.session.query(User).filter_by(id=current_user.id).delete()
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been deleted!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('settings.html', title='Account Settings')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite3 requires some coaxing to enforce foreign keys. You basically need to execute

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON
```

on each new connection. I do something like the following

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
... configure app
db.init_app(app)
if app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'].startswith('sqlite'):
    from sqlalchemy import event  # noqa
    from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine  #noqa

    @event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
    def _sqlite_fk_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
        cursor.close()
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/asyd/a7aadcf07a66035ac15d284aef10d458) provides a variation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a separate query to delete the posts.

`db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id == current_user.id).delete()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute `cascade` in your User model to achieve that:

```
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author',
                            lazy=True, cascade='delete')
```